# List index out of range error within while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I say to the code to get the value 1 of the array within a while loop?

```py
while line < 1000000:
    userpass = passfile.readline().split()
    line = line + 1
    up = userpass[1]
    print(userpass)
    up = decode(TH3, up)
    #See Values
    #print (line)
    #print (str(userpass))
    #print (str(userEntry))
    #Checking If Account Is Created
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DataBase.py", line 55, in <module>
    up = userpass[v]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation, it is very important in python.

Comment: Seemingly `userpass` has less than two elements. Print it out to see, what it contains. Next time, please post the full traceback of the error message. It contains valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

My error was that i did'nt append so the value userpass was replaced to a len of 2 to a len of 0  : 
    [] just added an if len > 0 : 
before

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `userpass`'s length is less than 2.
In python, lists, tuples and dictionaries are 0-indexed. Meaning if you want to access the first element, you should write it like :
`up = userpass[0]`